# Positioning svg x/y coordinates with css not working with iOS devices?

Tags: ios, css, d3.js, svg, responsive-design

According to the W3C styling guide for css/svg (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html) I should be able to position certain svg elements within css using the x/y attributes.

This works with chrome + the Samsung Galaxy S6 (not tried other models/browsers). However, this doesn't work in iOS and some window/htc devices that I've tried.

Here is the code I'm using (with the help of d3.js);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5">
<script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        @media handheld,
        screen and (max-width: 425px) {
            foreignObject {
                x: 30;
                y: 30;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        d3.selectAll("body")
            .append("svg")
            .append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 30)
            .attr("height", 30)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', 0)
            .html("hello")
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hkObXeq2gMrY1dxOgK7?p=preview) of the code also.

I was wondering if there was any kind of workaround for this? or if someone could recommend another way of adding responsive breakpoints for the x/y?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `handheld`? It is ignored (I think) by iOS and is defined (I think) as <=320px.

Comment: Oh also, `foreignObject` does not have great cross-browser support. If your goal is good coverage, I would think about doing away with it (and `handheld`)

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox 47/Ubuntu but works with Chrome/Ubuntu

Comment: @DavidGilbertson I have tried removing `handheld` and also changing `foreignObject` to `rect` but still have the same issue with iOS unfortunately

Comment: @TimB thanks for testing on Firefox - modified post, I shouldn't have assumed it would work on all browsers when I had only tested on chrome also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is SVG 2. SVG *2* is still in Working Draft stage. Browser vendors are implementing features, but I wouldn't put anything into production that relied on SVG2 features. Even caniuse.com hasn't introduced a 'can i use SVG 2' section yet. They're [discussing it here](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1143).

Now to answer your question :)

## Option 1

If you only want to *move* whole SVG chunks around the page, then you can use HTML for your responsive layout and SVG within that. Something like:

```
  <div class="responsive-wrapper">
    <svg width="100%" height="200">
      <rect x="10" y="10" height="200" width="200"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive-wrapper">
    <svg width="100%" height="200">
      <rect x="10" y="10" height="200" width="200"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Then

```
.responsive-wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .responsive-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
  }
}

rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

## Option two

https://jsbin.com/xesuma/1

is JavaScript, is more complex, and isn't going to scale well.

```
<svg width="100%" height="200">
  <rect id="rect-1" x="10" y="10" height="200" width="200"/>
</svg>
```

and something kinda nasty like:

```
var rect1El = document.getElementById('rect-1');
var currentWidth = rect1El.getAttribute('width');

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var newWidth = window.innerWidth > 400 ? 300 : 100;

  if (newWidth !== currentWidth) {
    rect1El.setAttribute('width', newWidth);
    currentWidth = newWidth;
  }
});
```